# Local Screen Sharing

Tags: screen-sharing

Is there any software available that supports local screen sharing between two or more computers? By local I mean sharing screens using a direct wired connection (ethernet?) or over a home WiFi network. Is there something built into Windows 10 Home edition that does this?

- only needs screen sharing capability (no remote desktop control required)
- It only needs to work on Windows.
- Must be free
- open source desirable but not required

Comment: TeamViewer can be configured for LAN only, IMHO.

Comment: Veyon can do it, but it quite hard to set up.

Comment: How about https://github.com/EslaMx7/ScreenTask - not the neatest UI, but might just do the job. I have no experience with it.

Comment: @Thomas Weller All your recommendations were helpful and It looks like Veyon is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It was obvious to me that there are already dozens of existing applications for such thing but somehow the Internet is successfully flooded by the Z*** company. I'm glad to see alternatives and look forward in this question to be answered more. Next time, @Nick, do not accept the first answer immediately. There is no "single answer for all questions" by definition. Masking the question as Answered makes people skip it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Veyon](https://veyon.io/) is a free software for classrooms.

- It is free. GPL, code available on [Github](https://github.com/veyon/veyon)
- It has screen sharing capability, called [Demonstration Mode](https://docs.veyon.io/en/latest/user/features.html#demonstration-mode)
- It [works on Windows](https://docs.veyon.io/en/latest/admin/installation.html#installation-on-a-windows-computer)

I am using it at home on Windows 10 Pro with my children (age 7 and 10), so I can sometimes have a look at what games they play. I have not used the demonstration mode yet, to be honest.

Drawbacks and potential downsides:

- I find the software quite hard to install and get up and running. At least it is when you want to do remote control in a secure way. But, at the same time, I can't really think of a way on how to make it easier.
- I opened a few issues on Github for which the response often was "if you want new features, please ask our sales department for an offer". So, that's not a group of enthusiasts, there's someone trying to earn a living (which is ok, too, but still a bit unexpected for GPL software).